# Multicast message to all my app's users

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have set in my application the google cloud messaging service and everything works but if i send a message to my application the messages are received only by the users that i know the deviceId. How i can send my message to all the devices that use my app ?

Thank You very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot send message to the devices that are not registered.

Firstly, those devices should register using the `GCMRegistrar.register` and send the registrationId to the server, then you can be able to send messages to those devices.

```
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context);

    if (!regId.equals("")) {
        // Device is alredy registered. This checks whether it is registered
        // on the server or not.
        if (!GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) {
            // Save regId to server
            registerInBackground(context, regId);
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
        }
    } else {
        GCMRegistrar.register(context, senderId);
    }
```

Comment: Yes I did this in my application but when the devices are registered how I can know the deviceId to send to they the text ?

Comment: you can check whether device is registered on server or not by using the following method. GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)

Comment: you are meant to store that on your server.

Comment: yes.you should store that id on the server and use it when sending notification.

Comment: I don't understand. I need a list of the devices that are registrated so i can send to this devices my text. isRegisteredOnServer(context) give me a boolean that show if the devices of the users are rigister or not. Please give me an example

Comment: @SmileApplications

[GCM](http://surl.co/?iqmgZ) check this tutorial on AndroidHive, Which will give you a rough idea.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to send GCM messages to devices that have not been registered.

If you need a fail safe broadcast to all devices, then it might be better to have your app do a periodic pull. A simple flat json file on a webserver with a version number would suffice, but the real pain is judging how often, when and how it is to be pulled.

Answer (score 1):

The client on the device receives a Registration ID from the GCM library on the device, which it is then supposed to send to your server via normal channels, along with whatever identifying information you want.  Your server needs to remember which RegID goes to which user or device.  For more information, see: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html